# How to use small photocell to trigger wake up pin for extremely low power consumption

Tags: microcontroller, low-power, photodiode, light-sensor, attiny85

I want to trigger microcontroller wake up event using a photocell that produces voltage when light.
I have BPW46 photocell and ATTiny85 in deep sleep, interrupt is configured to be trigered by PB3 pin change. I checked that using only pin change for wake, the ATTiny85 uses below 1 microamp in sleep mode and thi is OK.

I need to wake up only if the surronding light changes.

I put BPW46 photocell between PB3 and GND and it basicallt works - light change triggers waking up, but the sensitivity is low. Is there any other way of wiring photocell (mayby different cell? could you recommend?) and maintaining low current in sleep mode?

I know I could use watchdog and wake up periodically to check light with photoresistor, but it takes more current.

BPW46 specs: https://pdf1.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/view/1468100/VISHAY/BPW46.html

Comment: Please [edit] to include a hyperlink to the datasheet for the BPW46 that you are using.

Comment: How about an ultralow power comparator like the https://www.analog.com/en/products/adcmp380.html#product-overview Which could be used to detect a 0.5V signal on the photocell.

Comment: @user1937198 comparator looks promising. How to wire it to GPIO and photocell? Are there any alternatives to ADCMP380? It's not easily accessible...

Comment: @user1937198 oh and something more soldering-friendly, like THT?

Comment: @user1937198 I found LM393P which is low power too (below 1 microamp). Still, not really sure how to wire it.

Comment: LM393P needs 2.5 mA supply current and a resistor add the output, so this is not a low power solution. A comparator with push/pull output like MCP6541 is a better option here because there is no current flow in a pullup resistor at the output.

Comment: This one is available at Mouser, thanks!

Comment: @user1937198 still, wiring diagram or hint would by helpful.

Comment: @user1937198 As I understand voltage comparator needs some voltage to compare to, so one pin will be conntected to photocell, but how to supply treshold voltage to second pin without draining battery?

Comment: @PanJanek In the case of the ADCMP380 thats a fixed voltage reference integrated in the chip, that you divide the input to compare against. For something like a MCP6541 you would need to use a high overall resistance voltage divider to generate the reference voltage.

Comment: @user1937198 ok so voltage divider with two resistors above 1M. Should I connect output of MCP6541 straight to the GPIO? I want to make sure that there is no leaking current...

Comment: @PanJanek Yes. The GPIO should be a high impedance input.